# Twitter Login not Open Login Window in my ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, twitter

I want to implement the Twitter Login in my iOS app. And save user credentials in my app. i have done all Twitter Setting from Twitter Developer. and get the Consumer Key and Secret Key. save it into Plist.  I am tried this code on button clicked but not open the Twitter Login window in my iOS app. why this happening.

i tried this code

```
    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
                                  ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                                  completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
----------> Debuger not going here         if (granted == YES)
         {
             NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account
                                         accountsWithAccountType:accountType];


             if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
             {
                 ACAccount *twitterAccount =
                 [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];
                 NSLog(@"11111111----%@",[[twitterAccount valueForKey:@"properties"]valueForKey:@"user_id"]);


                 NSDictionary *message = @{@"status": @" First Twitter post from iOS6"};

                 NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"];

                 SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest
                                           requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                           requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                           URL:requestURL parameters:message];

                 postRequest.account = twitterAccount;

                 [postRequest
                  performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                              NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                  {
                      NSLog(@"Twitter HTTP response: %i",
                            [urlResponse statusCode]);
                  }];
             }
         }
     }];
```

Please help me to solve this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`----------> Debuger not going here         if (granted == YES)`

May be you didn't have configure your twitter account in iOS's Settings.

OR you didn't allowed the access of twitter from your app by clicking on Disallow when twitter pop up appeared.

Cross check (Simulator) : `Settings->Privacy->Twitter` does your app appeared in list ? If not then delete it and try again.

Working code :

```
    accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init]; // Declare it in .h file (for testing)
    ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    NSArray *twitterAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];

    // Runing on iOS 6
    if (NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") && [SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType options:NULL completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             if (granted) // User already login in default Twitter application
             {
             }
         }];
    }
```

Comment: Now what is FBLogin ?

Comment: sorry it was my mistake to..this is not error...  not happening anything when user clicked on twiiter button actionn..

Comment: @Namo: check updated answer. Please declare `accountStore` in `.h` file